# Can't have a children prop array with only one child?

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I'm quite new to React and tried taking a shot at creating a Navbar.
But I ran into a problem which I can't seem to wrap my head around I've got following Component:

```
interface Props {
    children: React.ReactElement<Navitem>[];
}

export class Navbar extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"navbar"}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

aswell as a Navitem component:

```
interface Props{
    label?: string;
}

export class Navitem extends React.Component<Props, {}>{
    render(){
        return <p>{this.props.label}</p>
    }
}
```

When trying to create a the navbar tho as follows:

```
    <Navbar>
       <Navitem label={"Item 1"}/>
    </Navbar>
```

I get this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'ReactElement<Navitem, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>[] | ... 6 more ... | (ReactElement<...>[] & ReactPortal)' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.
  This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'ReactElement<Navitem, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>[] | ... 6 more ... | (ReactElement<...>[] & ReactPortal)' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.  TS2769
```

When trying it with multiple Navitems as the error message suggests it works.

So finally to my question: Is it not possible to have an children prop array with only one element in it or am I just missing something. Any help is appreciated!

(**FYI** I know I could do
`children: React.ReactElement<Navitem>[] | React.ReactElement<Navitem>;` but then I would have to check if it was a single object or an array everytime I want to do something with it)

Comment: Might be helpful: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap I believe this will work even if there is a single child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem for my component when I try to pass single child to array of children type. We can avoid this error by manually create array with single child and key in JSX.

```
<Navbar>
   {[<Navitem key="1" label={"Item 1"}/>]}
</Navbar>
```